# xpath for xquery in SQL

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery

I have a xml filed in sql table

the xml have the structure like these

```
<root>
<element>
<sub name="1">
<date>the date <date>
</sub>
<sub name="2">
<date>the date <date>
</sub>
<sub name="3">
<date>the date <date>
</sub>
.....
<element>
</root>
```

how i can get the date of the element with the name 1?

I have prove :

```
 /root/element/sub[Name = "1"]/date/text()
```

but nothing hapen.

any  ideas?

Comment: case sensitive ? `Name != name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
DECLARE @Input XML 
SET @input = '<root>
<element>
<sub name="1">
<date>the date</date>
</sub>
<sub name="2">
<date>the date</date>
</sub>
<sub name="3">
<date>the date</date>
</sub>
</element>
</root>'

SELECT 
    @input.value('(/root/element/sub[@name="1"]/date)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

You need to use `@name` to get the XML **attribute** `name` - without the `@`, it's trying to find an XML **element** (instead of the attribute)